# Proving an inequality with multiple Variables

Tags: proof-explanation

I was thinking of using induction, but i am not sure how to use induction when I have two variables $x$ and $y$.  Can I just prove it for any $x$ and make $y$ a certain real number like $2$?

For real numbers $x, y, z$, and $x, y \geq 0$, prove that 
$$\frac{x+y}{2} \geq\sqrt{xy}.$$

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What about $z$? It is not present in your inequality, which seems to be the classical AM-GM inequality. We have $(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2\ge 0$, so $$x+y-2\sqrt{xy}\ge 0$$ which, after small rearrangment gives us $$\frac{x+y}{2}\ge\sqrt{xy}.$$

Comment: z is part of a different part of the problem sorry.  There is no z here.  But where are you getting this (sqrtx-sqrty)^2 is greater than or equal to 0??

Comment: Oh, because any square power is non-negative. This is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

It's the classical **AM-GM inequality** which can be **generalized for n variables**:

> $$\frac{\sum x_i}{n}\ge \prod{x_i}$$

and also it can be generalized for any exponent defining the **p-Mean**:

> $$M(p)=\sqrt[p]\frac{\sum x_i^p}{n}$$

it can be shown that:

> $$p_1\geq p_2 \iff M(p_1) \geq M(p_2)$$

Note that: $AM = M(1)$ and $GM=M(p) \quad p\to 0$

Comment: What is AM-GM inequality

Comment: @tskgreen take a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means and here https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality